# Fancybox modal scrolling breaks with changing address and menu bars on iOS Safari and Android

Tags: jquery, mobile, fancybox

I have used Fancybox to build an ajax modal quick look lightbox for my website. It works well across browsers however on iOS Safari and Android the changing sizes of the app address bar and menu bar temporarily breaks the design.

My modal window has a max height of 96%. If it is taller than the screen size, as is often the case, then you can scroll up and down with touch. So far so good. However if you reach the end, or top, and then 'push' it further the app address bar and menu is activated (shrinks/enlarges/appears/disappears) and the background of the page begins to scroll. Focus therefore is lost from the lightbox and it is not until the background stops scrolling and you do not interact that the focus returns, correctly, to the lightbox.

This results in a poor and confusing user experience as the lightbox itself is not scrolling and my custom close button, located at the top, is not always visible. Since this is a behaviour of the browser app rather than the web page I have been unable to find a solution.

I am using the latest version of Fancybox - 3.5.7.

The basic setup of my code is as follows:

```
<a class="quicklook" data-fancybox-quicklook data-type="ajax" data-src="quicklook.ajax.php">Quick Look</a>
```

```
//jquery
$('[data-fancybox-quicklook]').fancybox({
  touch: false,
  btnTpl: { smallBtn: false }
  });
```

quicklook.ajax.php:

```
<div class="quicklook_lightbox">    

  <!--- lightbox content --->

</div>
```

```
/* css */
div.quicklook_lightbox {
  width: 97%;
  padding: 1.4em;
  max-height: 96%;
  }
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It is just not possible to 100% avoid address-bar size change when user taps nearby. But next major release of fancybox will support Visual Viewport API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Visual_Viewport_API) and that will greatly improve usability on mobile devices. Sadly, that API is available only recently, starting from iOS 13.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, understand. It is unfortunate that at present it is not possible to improve the experience for the user on mobile. I guess I will have to decide if it is a deal breaker!